# Google Mock: How to configure custom message to explain match failure

Tags: c++, googlemock

In case of match failure Google mock prints message like the following:

> test.cpp:112: EXPECT_CALL(mock_obj, foo( **MyMatcher**( **bar** ) ))...
>   **Expected arg #0**: is equal to [1,2; 3,4]
>   **Actual**: { 1 }
>   Expected: to be called once
>   Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

Using custom matcher **MyMatcher** I'm able to define a description string which is used to generate the failure message when the match fails. But it defines only **Expected arg #0** part of message. Is there any way how I can customize how **Actual** is printed?

In my case I can't overload operator<< for class of **bar** as it already overloaded by third party code is not under my control (this library define class of **bar** and operator<< for it).

Comment: Since Google Mock is built upon Google Test, I'm going to assume that this applies: https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Teaching_Google_Test_How_to_Print_Your_Values (but I haven't tried it myself).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I'm **not** able to define `operator` `<<` for my `class`, google test have option to define `PrintTo` function for it [Teaching Google Test How to Print Your Values](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#teaching-google-test-how-to-print-your-values). Thanks [RA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214762/ra) for the link.

> A user can override this behavior for a class type Foo by defining an overload of PrintTo() in the namespace where Foo is defined.  We give the user this option as sometimes defining a << operator for Foo is not desirable (e.g. the coding style may prevent doing it, or there is already a << operator but it doesn't do what the user wants).

```
void PrintTo(const Bar& value, ::std::ostream* os);
```

Comment: The link was moved: [Teaching Google Test How to Print Your Values](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values)

Comment: @BradvanderLaan Here's a static link to that section in the docs: [Teaching googletest How to Print Your Values](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/1a8ecf1813d022cc7914e04564b92decff6161fc/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values)